# How do I make a custom range input slider using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, code-snippets

I am searching for a library that would help me create cross-platform compatible range inputs. I know that there is a css-only possibility, but in this case I'd rather depend on JS solution (for backwards compatibility). Do you now of a solution which I could use?

Thanks in advance,

Chrisstar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this Css script:

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  width: 100%; 
  background: transparent; 

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none; }

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent; 
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I am aware that you can do this, but I'd rather depend on a js solution.

Comment: Check these source files :
https://github.com/Stryzhevskyi/rangeSlider
https://github.com/tovic/range-slider

Comment: Rangeslider is a good JQUERY based Extension . This Might help you .http://rangeslider.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```js
var rangeSlider = function(){
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
      range = $('.range-slider__range'),
      value = $('.range-slider__value');
    
  slider.each(function(){

    value.each(function(){
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function(){
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 60px 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    padding: 60px;
  }
}

.range-slider {
  margin: 60px 0 0 0%;
}

.range-slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(100% - (73px));
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2c3e50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}

::-moz-range-track {
  background: #d7dcdf;
  border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="250" min="0" max="500" step="50">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="400" min="0" max="500">
  <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>
```

I made it with SCSS, which cannot be cmpiled on SO, so [here is a link](https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/CeLqA) to my original precompiled version.

It's custom html & css based. The actions are being handled by js.